# Speeding up a Python nditer with a for loop in Python with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, montecarlo

I want to speed up the following Python code. Not sure what I can do to speed up the code below.

```
with np.nditer(cmpd_array, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
   for x in it:
      x[...] = sum(np.random.choice(SIS_Array_Norm, x))
      count += 1
```

[image]

EDIT: Here is the C++ implementation that I made based on the Python program to better explain what I am doing in Python. The C++ code is slightly faster.

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> calculateMonteCarlo(std::vector<std::vector<int>> cmpdArray, std::vector<float> sisNormalized)
{
    auto newVector = std::vector<std::vector<int>>();
    auto count = 0;

    for (auto& it : cmpdArray)
    {
        auto tmpVector = std::vector<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < it.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Monte Carlo Simulation: " << count << std::endl;

            auto poissonChoice = randomChoice(sisNormalized, it[i]);
            auto sum = vectorSum(poissonChoice);

            tmpVector.push_back(sum);
            count++;
        }

        newVector.push_back(tmpVector);
    }

    return newVector;
}
```

Comment: `nditer` is not a speed tool.  Rewrite this as an ordinary loop,  Instead of the image, give a couple of small sample arrays, along with result.  And may be an explanation of what you are attempting to do.

Comment: The big time consumer is calling that `sum...choice` once for each element of `cmpd_array`.  `nditer` does not 'compile' anything; it's just an iteration tool.